# create nested json programmatically from different sources

Tags: python, json

i have to request an API for an id (ClientHierId) with each one of those Id's i have to make multiple requests to other 2 API's in order to retrieve the rest of the fields and i have to create a nested json with the following structure

```
diction = {"ClientHiers": [{"Attributes" :[{"AttributeValues": [{'ServiceMonth':'06/2022','Value':'10'},{'ServiceMonth':'07/2022','Value':'20'}],'ClientAttributeId':"31",'CurrencyId':'1'},{"AttributeValues": [{'ServiceMonth':'06/2022','Value':'15'},{'ServiceMonth':'07/2022','Value':'10'}],'ClientAttributeId':"32",'CurrencyId':'0'}],"ClientHierId":'999'}]}


{
    "ClientHiers": [
        {
            "Attributes": [
                {
                    "AttributeValues": [
                        {
                            "ServiceMonth": "06/2022",
                            "Value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "ServiceMonth": "07/2022",
                            "Value": "20"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ClientAttributeId": "31",
                    "UOM_CurrencyId": "1"
                },
                {
                    "AttributeValues": [
                        {
                            "ServiceMonth": "06/2022",
                            "Value": "15"
                        },
                        {
                            "ServiceMonth": "07/2022",
                            "Value": "10"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ClientAttributeId": "32",
                    "UOM_CurrencyId": "0"
                }
            ],
            "ClientHierId": "999"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I constantly add values ​​to this structure based on the ClientHierId?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a [questions and answers
site](https://stackoverflow.com/about), not a code-writing service. Please read
through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your
question to reflect your work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do something that is not possible, at least without using some kind of framework. You cannot generate code like you want it because there is no way to know what attributes will be present or how many times they might appear. This means that if you try to write your own generator, then it would need to read all the data first before generating any code which would take too long and cause performance issues. Also, even if you could figure out how to get around these problems, you wouldn't necessarily end up with valid code.
The only thing you can really do here is use a library that does this work for you already. Luckily, python has several options available for doing exactly what you're asking about. The most popular ones being:

- Marshmallow - A flexible schema mapping system built on top of Mako templates. It allows you to define schemas for both creating and reading objects as well as validation rules.
- Flask-Restless - An extension for flask that provides support for defining database models by extending marshmallow. It also adds support for migrations and serialization/deserialization.
- Peewee - A lightweight ORM designed specifically for working with PostgreSQL databases. It uses reflection to map model classes onto table definitions and supports inheritance through proxy models.
- MongoEngine - An object-document mapper for Python 3 and MongoDB. Supports document creation and update operations along with querying capabilities.
- Elixir - A full featured Object Relational Mapper (ORM) written in pure Python. It offers features such as optimistic concurrency control, transactions, eager loading, lazy loading, dynamic queries, automatic relationship fixup, and more.
- Pyramid - A web application development framework that focuses on productivity, flexibility, extensibility, and developer happiness. It includes tools for routing, view composition, form handling, testing, deployment, etc.
- SQLAlchemy - A toolkit for declarative database programming. It implements a domain specific language that maps closely to SQL while providing an interface optimized for SQL generation and consumption.
- Alembic - A migration framework for database systems. It helps automate common tasks related to database migrations, e.g., applying changes to the database when running tests against the application.